# custom query to show records with duplicate count with its duplicate occurance

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please refer below script

```
            declare @table1 table
            (
            col1 int
            )  

            insert into @table1 values(1)
            insert into @table1 values(3)
            insert into @table1 values(3)
            insert into @table1 values(6)
            insert into @table1 values(4)
            insert into @table1 values(4)
            insert into @table1 values(4)
```

The below query gives

```
            select col1 ,COUNT(col1) cntCol1 from @table1 group by col1
```

this output

```
            ----------------
            col1   | cntCol1
            -------| -------
            | 1    | 1    | 
            | 3    | 2    | 
            | 4    | 3    | 
            | 6    | 1    | 
            ---------------
```

is it possible to get the below output

```
            ----------------
            col1   | cntCol1
            -------| -------
            | 1    | 1    | 
            | 3    | 1    | 
            | 3    | 2    |  
            | 4    | 1    |  
            | 4    | 2    |  
            | 4    | 3    | 
            | 6    | 1    | 
            ---------------
```

If so, could you please help me with the query.

Thanks, 
Esen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### SQL Fiddle

```
      SELECT col1, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by col1 order by col1) cntCol1
        FROM @table1
    ORDER BY col1, cntCol1
```

**Sample Data**:

```
 declare @table1 table
            (
            col1 int
            )  

            insert into @table1 values(1)
            insert into @table1 values(3)
            insert into @table1 values(3)
            insert into @table1 values(6)
            insert into @table1 values(4)
            insert into @table1 values(4)
            insert into @table1 values(4)
```

**Results:**

```
| COL1 | CNTCOL1 |
------------------
|    1 |       1 |
|    3 |       1 |
|    3 |       2 |
|    4 |       1 |
|    4 |       2 |
|    4 |       3 |
|    6 |       1 |
```

Comment: Thank you. Though you answered 20 seconds latter than @marc_s, I am accepting your answer because of its detailed nature.

Comment: Much obliged, Esen. Thanks. I also added `ORDER BY` so that the numbers in CNTCOL1 won't jump around, because you can get it in a different order without the clause.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
select 
    col1, 
    Sequence = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY col1 ORDER BY col1)
from 
    @table1
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function dishes out consecutive numbers, starting at 1, for each "partition" of data (in your case: for each distinct value of `col1` in your table)

Answer (score 1):

```
select *, rn=row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1 )
  from @table1
```